# Upload, read, write and download HTML file in SAPUI5 application

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, sapui5

I would like to create a SAPUI5 application in which an HTML file can be uploaded. The contents of the file should be read in the next step. After the header tag, an additional text will be inserted in the content and the new file will be made available for download. To make it more clear:

1. Upload existing HTML file
2. Edit HTML file with additional text
3. Make edited HTML file available for download

Any ideas?

Comment: do you need some extra formatting options for editing an HTML file online (like in SAP Web IDE)? Or just a TextArea is sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is fairly easy to do this with pure UI5, without needing to use something like WebIDE.

You need to use three classes in particular:

- [sap.ui.unified.FileUploader](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.unified.FileUploader/overview): A control for uploading the file.
- [sap.ui.codeeditor.CodeEditor](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.codeeditor.CodeEditor): A control for displaying and edition the code (has syntax highlighting).
- [sap.ui.core.util.File](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.util.File): A utility class for downloading the contents.

Assuming that you don't want to do a backend round-trip for reading the file, you can also use the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) API.

So these are the steps that you need to make:

1. Add a file uploader in your view:

```xml
<u:FileUploader change="onChangeFile" />
```

2. Create a handler in the controller for reading the file:

```js
onChangeFile: function(oEvent) {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var oReader = new FileReader();
    oReader.onload = function() {
        oModel.setProperty("/code", oReader.result);
    }
    oReader.readAsText(oEvent.getParameter("files")[0]);
},
```

3. Add the code editor control and a download button:

```xml
<Button text="Download" press="onDownload" />
<ce:CodeEditor type="html" value="{/code}" height="300px" />
```

4. Create a handler for doing the download itself:

```js
onDownload: function() {
    var sText = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/code");
    File.save(sText, "download", "html");
}
```

You can find a working fiddle of this here: https://jsfiddle.net/5z7deeyd/1/.

---

**Later edit:**

If you just need to change the file without user interaction, then you only need steps 1 and 2. For step 2, the handler can look like this:

```js
onChangeFile: function(oEvent) {
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    var oReader = new FileReader();
    oReader.onload = function() {
        // do something with the oReader.result...
        var sNewContent = oReader.result + "something";
        File.save(sNewContent, "download", "html");
    }
    oReader.readAsText(oEvent.getParameter("files")[0]);
}
```

Comment: Hi Serban! I do not really need the CodeEditor control. The app should automatically add some fixed content (e.g. <img src="www.example.png" alt="some image" height="42" width="100">) after the header tag and make it ready for download. Is this also possible? Thanks so far.

Comment: Of course! You don't necessarily need to use the code editor itself. You can make the download happen immediately or wait for the user to press a button. For the first case, I edited the answer. For the second case, it is the same as with the code editor (you just store the updated code in the JSONModel directly without letting the user to change it by himself).

Comment: That sounds good! Just one more question: I tried getting the html content as string just by using `var content = oReader.result;` after `oReader.readAsText(oEvent.getParameter("files")[0]);`. This did not work for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `readAsText` method is asynchronous. The correct way of using the file reader is as shown in the example, but attaching a callback to the `onload` event.